# Old house wiring: black, white and brown

Tags: wiring

I need to install a socket in an old house which has three wires with faded colors I interpret as black, white and brown. I've determined that black is the hot one using a multimeter. The instructions I have for the socket are for black, white and green. Should I assume that I should wire the brown one as 'green'?
The colors below are faded but the hot "black" one is on the right, the "brown" one top left, the "white" one bottom left. This is in Austin, TX, USofA. The house was built in 1980.

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in question please?

Comment: Is the brown wire bare with no insulation/covering on it, or does it have brown wire covering?  Ground wire is a bare wire or has a green covering.

Comment: Brown wire covering

Comment: What part of the planet is this? In my part of the planet I'd guess from "old house" that it's an ungrounded system with black, white, and faded red that you see as brown. Please [edit] to add pictures and inform us where on the planet you are.

Comment: Added photo and updated the question.

Comment: Despite the focus issue, it's clear from the picture that the "brown" wire is simply bare copper that's oxidized - there's no insulation/covering on it. Might be some brown kraft paper, but that's not really "on" the wire.

Comment: Well I never... I did a 'tap test' and heard a clinging, metallic sound. So that's the bare grounding wire. Thank you that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should never assume anything about a wire based solely on its color. Get a multimeter and check actual voltage and/or actual connection to a known ground.

Comment: I was about to say that this should be a comment, but, to be fair, this exactly answers the question asked.  +1 OP just needs to ask a better question... ;)

Comment: I've already checked the voltage with a meter. That's how I was able to determine that the black one is the hot one. Not sure what else I can check.

Comment: @FreeMan "OP just needs to ask a better question". Any suggestions to how to make my question "better" would be appreciated.

Comment: They only question you asked, @Ya. was "Should I assume that I should wire the brown one as 'green'?" and this directly and correctly answers that question. Your question, after several edits, is much better.